# Installing Windows service on Windows 8.1 tablet

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013, windows-services, windows-store-apps, installutil

I Have Written a WCF service , to perform some image processing activity, Hosted on windows service . A windows 8.1 Store App consumes this WCf service. I had run this setup in my local machine and was successful.
 Now i need to install this this entire setup in a windows 8.1 tablet which neither has a Visual studio nor developer cmd prompt, how would i achieve this . Kindly Help...

Comment: Is it an ARM Tablet? If so, you can't. WinRT aka Windows for ARM processors you can't connect an App to a local WCF service (in fact you can't connect to the loopback/localhost at all, independent of service or protocol used). Though you can connect to a remote service if you add the URL to the App manifest as far as I know. All connections to localhost/loopback are disabled in WinRT/ARM devices running Windows

Comment: thank you for replying ...My tablet is intel core i3 processor with windows 8.1